# Correct use of tenses in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, future-tense

I have this sentence:

> Many who started with you, won't finish with you.

*Started* - past tense, *won't* - future simple.

Shouldn't it be "would not finish with you"?

I think we can't mix the tenses like past tense and future tense in one sentence. What do you think?

Comment: I read this question, but I will not comment on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["won't" vs. "wouldn't"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20491/wont-vs-wouldnt)

Comment: We eat breakfast this morning but I won't join you for dinner. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The two part refer to different times, one in the past, one in the future. Absolutely no reason why they cannot do so.

Comment: Where did this rule come from, that one should not mix tenses in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you, along with with your friends,  passed the medical test last month for going abroad. And you will go tonight. Then you can say:

> *We who passed the medical test last month will go tonight*.

That's why there is nothing wrong to say "Many who started with you won't finish with you." because "won't finish with you" follows "many" not "who started with you".